# How to place svg on top of an svg?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm filling a table with svg line, svg circle, or both at the same time. the problem is when I fill a cell with a line + a circle the line is under the circle not on top. so how can I fix this?

```
<td height="20" width="20" align="center" valign="center" class="col3 row6">
    <svg height="18" width="18">
        <circle cx="9" cy="9" r="6" fill="red"></circle>
    </svg>
    <svg height="20" width="20">
        <line x1="0" y1="9" x2="20" y2="9" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:5"></line>
    </svg>
</td>
```

Comment: Either move the `<line>` element into the same `<svg>` element, or position the svg elements absolutely over another. The latter might not work due to funky `position: absolute` support in table cells in some browsers.

Comment: I can't move it because I'm using js to place it like this : `document.getElementById('tbl').rows[x].cells[y].innerHTML +=` `//circle+line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could absolutely position your svg tags and place them on top of each other.

For example:

```css
td {
  position: relative;
}

td svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

svg.circle {
  left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<td height="20" width="20" align="center" valign="center" class="col3 row6">
    <svg class="circle" height="18" width="18">
        <circle cx="9" cy="9" r="6" fill="red"></circle>
    </svg>
    <svg class="line" height="20" width="20">
        <line x1="0" y1="9" x2="20" y2="9" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:5"></line>
    </svg>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but how to fix the circles, they are not perfectly in the center, I tried removing `left:1px` but nothing

Comment: maybe try removing the `top: 1px`, updated the answer

Comment: that didn't do it